# $this->stop_server = TRUE doesn't work

Tags: php

This is the childSignalHandler, which I use to control the signals in my PHP project.

```
public function childSignalHandler($signo, $pid = null, $status = null) {

    switch($signo) {
        case SIGTERM:
            $this->log('Платформа получила сигнал SIGTERM, завершение работы...');
    $this->stop_server = TRUE;
    exec('killall ffmpeg');             
            break;
        case SIGKILL:
            $this->log('Платформа получила сигнал SIGKILL, завершение работы...');  
    $this->stop_server = TRUE;
    exec('killall ffmpeg');                 
            break;
```

However,

> $this->stop_server = TRUE;

seems not to be working

> var_dump($this->stop_server);

returns this: bool(false)

Full code is here: https://github.com/mironoff111/PartCCTV/blob/master/backend/PartCCTVClass.php

Comment: I'd rather not dig through your entire codebase on GitHub. Are you sure the switch statement is executing the way you expect? Ie, it is possible that no case is being selected? Are SIGTERM and SIGKILL constants defined elsewhere?

Comment: `var_dump($this->stop_server);` where?

Comment: @u_mulder
var_dump($this->stop_server); at line 106.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter

Switch is working fine, as it successfully writes to the log. The function is defined here (line 27):
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, array($this, "childSignalHandler"));
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, array($this, "childSignalHandler"));